# How can i make a horizontal scrolling list View builder with dynamic height?

Tags: flutter, listview, responsive-design, builder

```
//ListView Builder
Container(
          height: 230,
          margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 30),
          child: ListView.separated(
            physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            itemCount: controller.homeData!.bestSaleWebinars.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) => InkWell(
                onTap: () {
                  Get.toNamed(RoutesName.allCoursesPageDetails);
                  allCoursesController.getAllCourseDetails(
                      controller.homeData!.bestSaleWebinars[index].slug);
                },
                child: newCoursesBuilder(
                    controller.homeData!.bestSaleWebinars[index])),
            separatorBuilder: (context, _) => const SizedBox(width: 15),
          ),
```

//widget
[image]

```
  Widget newCoursesBuilder(var coursesCategories) {
    return SizedBox(
      height: 350,
      width: 200,
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 4.0),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Container(
              height: 100,
              width: 200,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                  border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey)),
              child: CachedNetworkImage(
                imageUrl: "https://livedivine.in${coursesCategories.thumbnail}",
                placeholder: (context, url) => Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    image: DecorationImage(
                        image: AssetImage(
                          Images.logo,
                        ),
                        fit: BoxFit.fill),
                  ),
                ),
                errorWidget: (context, url, error) => Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    image: DecorationImage(
                        image: AssetImage(
                          Images.logo,
                        ),
                        fit: BoxFit.fill),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 11, top: 8),
              child: Text(
                coursesCategories.title,
                style: TextStyle(
                    color: ColorConst.buttonColor,
                    fontSize: 15,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w900),
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      const Icon(
                        Icons.person,
                        size: 16,
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 4.0),
                        child: Text(
                          coursesCategories.teacher.fullName,
                          style: const TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.black,
                              fontSize: 12,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      const Icon(
                        Icons.calendar_month,
                        size: 16,
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 4.0),
                        child: Text(
                          "${coursesCategories.duration}",
                          style: const TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.black,
                              fontSize: 12,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 2,
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  Text(
                    coursesCategories.price.toString(),
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color: ColorConst.buttonColor,
                        fontSize: 20,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w800),
                  ),
                  Text(
                    "${coursesCategories.status}"
                        .replaceFirst("Status.", "")
                        .toLowerCase(),
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color: ColorConst.buttonColor,
                        fontSize: 19,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w800),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: You like to remove height before `ListView` btw your card seems fixed height.

Comment: @Yeasin Sheikh tried removing height before lisview it disappeared completely also expanded and intrinsic height also not working

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the List view builder in an [IntrinsicHeight](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/IntrinsicHeight-class.html) widget, so the height of the ListView builder will be dynamic

Comment: no its not working

Comment: This should practically work when u dont know the height of each card, so you would not be able to constraint the list view builder so in these case wrapping the list view builder in an intrinsic height should resolve this

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `SingleChildScrollView`

```
SingleChildScrollView(
  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
  child: Row(
      children: List.generate(
    44,
    (index) => Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10),
      child: Container(
         ...
      ),
    ),
  )),
)
```